# How to resize the width of text input within bootstrap table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Bootstrap 2.3 and I have like 7 text input fields inside a table that uses bootstrap table style. I would like to resize (or shrink the width of) these text inputs instead of taking the whole width of the table cell but I could not do that

I tried to use the class of `span1` but it did not shrink them well. **So is there any way of minimizing the size or width of all text input fields within the table cell?**

Here's my code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Exercise</th>
                        <th>Exercise Code</th>
                        <th>Initiated by</th>
                        <th>Initiated on</th>
                        <th>Done by</th>
                        <th>Q1</th>
                        <th>Q2</th>
                        <th>Q3</th>
                        <th>Q4</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: could you post a link to your site so we can see the unwanted behaviour?

Comment: it seems you linked not 2.3 version of bootstrap. by the link: `http://www.bootply.com/TRUEb0epAv` all works right if bootstrap 2.3 is set. Against this if to set bootstrap 3.3, all _inputs_ are getting their width to 100% of cell width

Comment: Anyway you can set `.span1 { width: 50% !important}` and it should work right. Change `50%` to what you wish

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to JQuery, try doing this in your `<header>` area of html, but be sure it is after all Javascript includes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".span1").css("width", "10px");
</script>
```

If the above works, I think you need to update your original post to show all your js/css includes. This seems like you just have something in the wrong order.

## --Original Answer Below--

Could you not simply add a CSS entry in your header like:

```
.table > input[type="text"] {
    width: 10px;
}
```

The only negative is that this will change all table type=text elements that use the .table class.

So instead, have the table itself have the span1 tag and change the above code to reflect it?

```
.span1 > input[type="text"] {
    width: 10px;
}
```

*Note: Make sure this is AFTER you reference the bootstrap css.

Comment: It did not minimize it too much. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @TechnologyLover I updated answer, but I think you need to just give us more code or a link so we can see exactly what you have.